# Getting videos from a user's playlist -YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a way to get a listing of videos from a specific user's playlist? I tried the following call, but it doesn't seem to be giving me a list of videos in that playlist

feed://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/USERNAME/playlists/PLAYLIST_ID

Thanks in advance,

Scott

Answer (score 19):

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLAYLIST_ID

**Update**

Just to add to this answer
The url above... works however as @crunkchitis mentioned below.

> This wouldn't work for me because I was using the wrong playlist ID.
>   My playlists looked like "PL123456789" but make sure just to ditch the
>   "PL" and use "123456789" as your playlist ID!! – @crunkchitis

If you need a way to extract this info... using PHP...

```
<?php $cont = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/[PLAYLIST_ID]/?v=2&alt=json&feature=plcp')); ?>
<?php $feed = $cont->feed->entry; ?>
<?php if(count($feed)): foreach($feed as $item): // youtube start ?>
   <?php echo $item->title->{'$t'}  ?> <br />
   <?php echo $item->{'media$group'}->{'media$description'}->{'$t'}  ?>
<?php endforeach; endif; // youtube end ?>
```

user `print_r($item)` should you need other information such as thumbnail url, id etc...

Hope it helps

Comment: This wouldn't work for me because I was using the wrong playlist ID. My playlists looked like "PL123456789" but make sure just to ditch the "PL" and use "123456789" as your playlist ID!!

Comment: Hi, this answer is great, but I can't figure out how to get the ID/url of the video. Is there any way you could help?

Comment: Please note that this is no longer available. It is advisable to use "YouTube API v3.0" now.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually be struggling with this myself. Ive found it. but its not exactly easy to get to. Im using the json. So if you are using xml you need to add "&alt=json" to then end of your url.

I found under the entry array. in the media$group->media$content->media$thumbnail they have a list of the thumbnails for the video. Each one of these contains the video id in their path. Not the best solution but it should work just fine.

```
"media$group": {
        "media$content": [
            {
                "url": "http://www.youtube.com/p/PLE7C605988F1AFDAA",
                "type": "application/x-shockwave-flash",
                "yt$format": 5
            }
        ],
        "media$thumbnail": [
            {
                "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/[VIDEO_ID]/default.jpg",
                "height": 90,
                "width": 120,
                "yt$name": "default"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/[VIDEO_ID]/mqdefault.jpg",
                "height": 180,
                "width": 320,
                "yt$name": "mqdefault"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/[VIDEO_ID]/hqdefault.jpg",
                "height": 360,
                "width": 480,
                "yt$name": "hqdefault"
            }
        ],
        "media$title": {
            "$t": "[VIDEO_NAME]",
            "type": "plain"
        }
    },
```